# How to turn strings of numbers into nested lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to turn a list containing strings of numbers into a nested list, with the numbers within each string separated into individual integers that I can iterate over. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
l = [
    "400000,2003,2022,83,80,51,42",
    "400001,2001,2023,61,46,90,75",
    "400002,2003,2022,75,100,90",
    "400003,2001,2021,74,54,76,92",
    "400004,2000,2022,55,71,75,83",
    "400005,2000,2023,84,85,78,50",
    "400006,1999,2022,45,68,52,85",
]
new = str(l[1])
print(new)
new.split(",")
print(new)
```

The output looks the exact same, so the .split doesn't seem to work here. I need it to look like the following, where I can call l[0][1] and get 2003 as an int. Please without using pandas or other imported libraries, thank you!

```
400000, 2003, 2022, 83, 80, 51, 42,
400001, 2001, 2023, 61, 46, 90, 75,
```

Comment: When you call `new.split(',')` it returns a list. But you don't use the return value. `new` itself doesn't change (a string is immutable).

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can split each line and convert strings to integers.

To do that, you can use a simple comprehension list:

```py
matrix = [list(map(int, line.split(","))) for line in l]
```

The result would be:

```py
[[400000, 2003, 2022, 83, 80, 51, 42],
 [400001, 2001, 2023, 61, 46, 90, 75],
 [400002, 2003, 2022, 75, 100, 90],
 [400003, 2001, 2021, 74, 54, 76, 92],
 [400004, 2000, 2022, 55, 71, 75, 83],
 [400005, 2000, 2023, 84, 85, 78, 50],
 [400006, 1999, 2022, 45, 68, 52, 85]]
```

This comprehension list could be transformed into a classic `for` loop, like bellow:

```py
matrix = []
for line in l:
    matrix.append(list(map(int, line.split(","))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [eval(s) for s in l]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
[(400000, 2003, 2022, 83, 80, 51, 42), (400001, 2001, 2023, 61, 46, 90, 75), (400002, 2003, 2022, 75, 100, 90), (400003, 2001, 2021, 74, 54, 76, 92), (400004, 2000, 2022, 55, 71, 75, 83), (400005, 2000, 2023, 84, 85, 78, 50), (400006, 1999, 2022, 45, 68, 52, 85)]
```

Comment: Why [`eval`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) if there's the safe [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

Comment: Please, don't use `eval` to perform such a simple string to integer conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a beginner so thank you for introducing eval() to me!

Comment: `eval` is perfectky safe if the data is coming from a known source.  If there is the possibility for malicious input, then `ast.literal_eval` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `new.split(',')` a value. This will fix it:

```
new_list = [a.split(',') for a in l]
```